# How To Use Ajax Search In Laravel using a textbox and a button

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('searchName')}}" class="form-horizontal" id="formSearch">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <input type="text" name="contactname" id="txtSearch" class="form-control text-right"/>
                        <button class="btn btn-info pull-right" id="btnSearch" type="submit">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search">Search</i> </button>
                    </span>
                </form>
```

Above is my form in `index.blade.php` , and then i have bellow as ajax :

```
$('#formSearch').on('submit',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $('#txtSearch').val();
    var url = $('#formSearch').attr('action');
    $.get({
        url: url,
        data: name,
        success: function (datas) {
            console.log(datas);
        }
    })
})
```

and in my controller i have : in case you are wondering , Contact is the name of my model with a fillable in it :

```
public function searchNames(Request $request) {
    if($request->ajax()) {
        $contact = Contact::find($request->name);
        $gotyou = DB::select("SELECT id FROM contacts WHERE name = '$contact'");
        return response($gotyou);
    }
}
```

and in the route :

```
Route::get('/student/search','AjaxController@searchNames')->name('searchName');
```

i get undefiend in my console , i think my problem is i cant use get and post at the same time ! how can i post the text inside the textbox and search the database with that name , and return the record that has that name .

Comment: Just use POST , you cannot post data with GET.

Comment: @Wi used post too , but still nothing . when i use post i get what i typed in the textbox !!

Comment: Makes no sense, your query should send you `id` not the name string you sent.

Comment: @WilomGfx i used post , changed the Route to Route::post And Changed The Ajax $.get to $.post . but now i get an empty array ( and i know the name is there ) . but the id is not comming back . and that is exactly my problem

Comment: In jQuery `data: name,` should be `data: {name: name},`.

Comment: Somthing is veryyy Wrong in here

Comment: How did you pass model result to raw query as a string?!! First fix your controller and make sure the result of controller are correct. Anyway you may use Route::any to handle both GET & POST at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Few problems here... Just want to get you going in the right direction...

First, your route::get should be route::post in this case...

Then some direction for the refactoring of your controller function... I suggest you read the entire Laravel documentation... it is great and will only take you an hour or so... you will learn a lot from it...

```
public function searchNames(Request $request) {
    if($request->ajax()) {
        $contact = Contact::find($request->name);
        // $contact is actually an instance of the Contact model, not a name
        //$gotyou = DB::select("SELECT id FROM contacts WHERE name = '$contact->name'");
       // if you want to get a single value and not a collection, use ->value()
       $gotyou = DB::table('contacts')->where('name', $contact->name)->value('id');
        return response($gotyou);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#formSearch').on('submit',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $('#txtSearch').val();
    var url = $('#formSearch').attr('action');
    var post = $('#formSearch').attr('method');
    $.ajax({
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
        type: post,
        url: url,
        data: {name:name},
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data[0]);
        }
    })
})
```

Problem Fixed , And In The Controller , You can Get Data By Using
`$variable = $_POST['name']` remember we passed our textbox data using `name` , the code is mentioned above , then when you get it with $_POST['name'] , you can `return response($variable)` and get the result of the search back .